# I found two tags without a description

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the "partitions" and "encrypted-partitions" tag lack info. Should these be given a description?

https://askubuntu.com/tags/encrypted-partition/info
https://askubuntu.com/tags/partitions/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing tag wikis are common - Tags are created when there is a question that needs them, not when we feel like we should make a tag.

As such, usually a tag wiki is not added and by the time someone realizes, it has long been forgotten.

**That said**: [encrypted-partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encrypted-partition) is a synonym to [encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encryption), so there is really no need to add a tag wiki to it. The tag wiki for [encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encryption) should be sufficient.

[partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitions) on the other hand could use a tag wiki. Anyone can suggest an edit to these tag wikis, which then [has to be approved](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). And, as far as I can tell, there already is an edit pending.